# Adding an existing solution to Github from Visual Studio 2017 Mac

Tags: github, visual-studio-mac

I have looked many Xamarin articles and Github materials. All the given examples show how to add a project within a solution, but not the solution itself.

I am trying to add solution that has a Portable library and iOS project to GitHub. Can anyone tell me how to add the whole solution to Github from Visual Studio 2017 for Mac?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install GitHub extension for Visual Studio 2017 [HERE](https://visualstudio.github.com/index.html)

Then you can go through the tutorial [HERE](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/04/04/setting-up-and-using-github-in-visual-studio-2017/)

========= EDITED =======

For Visual Studio for Mac, please follow this guide: [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/set-up-git-repository)

If you face issue / error while following the guide, you may post it here with the specific error again.

Alternatively, you can also use other Git client in Mac. I'm currently using Tower in my Mac to connect to BitBucket and it works great.

- [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/)
- [Tower](https://www.git-tower.com)
- [Fork](https://git-fork.com/)
- [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)

Comment: Install link and tutorial links are for Visual Studio in Windows machine. My problem is in Mac

Comment: Great. Thanks. I will check out those links.

Comment: To clarify: The GitHub extension (which is a .vsix file) does NOT work on Visual Studio for Mac, as far as I can determine (tested on *Community* edition). So follow the tutorial in that Mac link, w/o trying to download that GitHub extension first :)